# How do I get a button to submit a form ASP.NET VS 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a deadline for an 'interview project' that I'm almost certain I've botched, but I, personally, NEED to know how this works! I've got a CRM that is the project of managing different employees as the project. Yes, it's full-stack development which I'm not up to snuff for, but I've tried saving this information to a MySQL database, which I couldn't get past a 500 error or 'user is not allowed on database' even though MySQL Workbench connected just fine.

Anyways, I'm now trying to save this information from this form into a CSV flat-file database. I'm accustomed much more to PHP, but the interviewing people want ASP.NET and I've learned everything I've coded in about a week that I happened to be moving in as well.

Regardless, here's the files, I can't make heads or tails of this right now and need to relax before I start my day job as a Customer Service Rep. (=_=)
The controller function in charge of this page:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Success(string Name, string StartDate, string Address, string Email, string PhoneNumber, string Position, string Department, Boolean Employment, string StartTime, string EndTime)
    {           
            string fileName = "data.csv";

            string folder = @"C:\ProgramData\";

            string fullPath = folder + fileName;

           string  query = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            query += " , " + Name + " , " + StartDate + " , " + Address + " , " + Email + " , " + PhoneNumber + " , " + Position + " , " + Department + " , " + Employment + " , " + StartTime + " , " + EndTime;
            using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath);
            writer.WriteLine(query);

        return Content(query);
    }
}
```

The .cshtml

```
 @model Conservice.Models.Add
@{ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { controller = "Team", action = "Success"})) ;

<h2>Add Member</h2>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Insert Hire Date (i.e. 2020-01-30)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="startDate" type="text" required="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Name</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="Name" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Address</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="Address" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Email Address</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="Email" type="text" required="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Preferred Phone Number</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" required="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Position</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="Position" type="text" required="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Department</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="Department" type="text" required="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Employment Status</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;<input name="Employment" type="radio" value="true"><label for="true">Employed</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="Employment" value="false" /><label for="false">Terminated</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Shift start time</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="StartTime" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Shift End Time</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="EndTime" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp; <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Team" asp-action="Success">Submit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The View for the landing page after the button press which displays a 405 error

```
    @model Conservice.Models.Member
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Success";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Success!</h2>
<br />
<p>
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Team" asp-action="Display">Continue</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your begin form statement:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { controller = "Team", action = "Success"})) ;
```

Will just write open and closed form tags before rest of html (see [docs about `using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) ). Change it to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { controller = "Team", action = "Success"}))
{
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Insert Hire Date (i.e. 2020-01-30)</td>
            <td>&nbsp;<input name="startDate" type="text" required="" /></td>
        </tr>
    ..... rest of the form
}
```

Comment: Should the button be outside of the Html.BeginForm scope?

Comment: @JacobCannon no, it should be inside also.

Comment: The page it's going to throw a 405 error. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @JacobCannon try `Html.BeginForm("Success", "Team", FormMethod.Post)`

Comment: @JacobCannon you already have `HttpPost` on `Success` in the question. Also I would say that you will need to transform it's parameter into a model.

Comment: So like in C++, where there's structs; but in C# I'd assign the values to a method before the page submits?